# StackOverflow editor

Tags: discussion

This question was asked many times, maybe this is duplicate, but I could not find appropriate answer for my needs:

I am developing web application where they can post codes and other texts and SO's text editor is very simple to use. My question:
Where can I get this SO's editor to use on my shared hosting plan with PHP and MySQL?

Answer (score -1):

You want a markdown interpreter.  I believe SO's is [redcarpet2](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet).  One project that uses it is [jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/), which may give you a chance to play around with it in your own environment with minimal coding needed.